# Android custom Facebook authentication flow

Tags: android, facebook, security, authentication, facebook-android-sdk

I have an application that requires authenticated users to access my apis and I was thinking on using Facebook Login and Google Sign in as authentication options...

Having read the best practices at: [facebook security best practices](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/security), I can use Facebook's access tokens in order to do that, but there are two problem with that:

1. Access tokens acquired by the Facebook Android SDK are of the 'long-lived' kind, meaning that they expire after 60 days... if somehow a token is stolen, the app is compromised for 60 days...
2. I need the token_secret to be stored in the client side. Although I'm still not sure how it is stored on the client, probably storing the secret on the client is not a good idea on the security point of view.

Having said that, I have a few questions:

1. Is this the most secure option?
2. Is there a way to retrieve the short-lived access token through the Facebook SDK? If not, what benefits could I have from the Facebook-Android-SDK since I will have to manually implement a custom login flow via webview...
3. If I go with this implementation, there is no possibility to make use of Facebook SSO, correct?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If this is an Android app, you can use the Login Button component that comes with the Android SDK. This will let you use the Facebook app or webview to login (which I presume is what you mean by SSO) and prevents the need to store your token_secret on the client.

Comment: How do you know the token_secret is not stored on the client?